# Cannot load file into MYSQL 8.0 with error 1290

Tags: mysql, file-upload

I am using MYSQL 8.0 on Windows and I cannot load files into the database from my computer. I get error 1290 "server running with secure-file-priv". I have spent two days working on this already and have gone over almost a dozen different answers here but none of them work. I have gone into the my.ini file and manually set "secure-file-priv" to "". Then when I check on the MYSQL workbench Options File under the Security tab it indeed shows a blank destination for "secure-file-priv". I have tried unchecking or checking the "secure-file-priv" on that Options File too and it makes no difference. When I run the query "show variables like 'secure-file-priv' it gives no results. Does anyone have an idea of what I can do to fix this?

Comment: The correct name is `show variables like 'secure_file_priv'` (`_` instead of `-`). It will always give a result. Your next steps will depend on what that variable contains. Your basic idea was correct (you need to correctly set it), but we do not know what you did exactly in the past 2 days. Also note that `null` means "disabled".

Comment: You are right, I needed the underscore. Thank you so much. However, I have now seen the folder name that the system is looking for and I placed my file to be loaded there. It is still not working. I get  the same error 1290 even with the file in the reserved uploads folder using this query: LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\table1.csv'
 INTO TABLE table1;

Comment: Try replacing all the \ in your filename by either \\ or /.

Comment: YES, the double \\ finally worked. Thank you. This seems a lot more complicated than it ought to be.